# IIS8 use web.config to rewrite url

Tags: web-config, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a website that lives within a folder one level off the root of the website. This was done because it used to host multiple web applications, but the other application has been retired and now the domain is used for just the site. We want to move it out of the folder and into the root of the domain

```
Current: website.com/main/page.php
Want: website.com/page.php
```

The issue is all the links that are out there that have the old location. I would like to have a .config file that lives in the old directory and have it re-direct to the link by just removing "main" from the URL. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Install IIS URL Rewrite module and study how to use it to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is by using HTTP redirect

This method is explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wC3kJnhlofw